# Is this particle always equilibrium vertically that is $Rsin(\alpha)=mg$ where $R$ is reaction on particle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

A thin smooth straight tube $OA$ is constrained to rotate with constant angular velocity $ω$ about a fixed vertical axis through $O$, and a particle is free to move in the tube. The angle between $OA$ and the upward vertical is a fixed acute angle $α$ and describe a fixed horizontal circle of radius $a$,
While the particle is in a state of steady motion the angular velocity of the tube is suddenly reduced to $\dfrac{\omega}{2}$ and is then maintained constant at the new value. Find
the time the particle takes to reach O,

My  problem is

Is this particle always equilibrium vertically that is $Rsin(\alpha)=mg$ where $R$ is reaction on particle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you resolve the forces, then $R cos(\alpha) + mg = ma sin(\alpha)$ as the motion of the particle is constrained within the tube, and it will try to move towards the center. Hence vertical motion will be **not be in equillibrium always, as there will be a vertical component of the net acceleration**.

Answer (score 0):

Before the angular velocity reduces, there is a constant zero vertical velocity on the contained object.  Because the vertical velocity is constant, requiring a zero vertical acceleration, the net vertical force is initially zero.  When the angular velocity decreases, acceleration along the pipe develops.  Vertical acceleration and vertical net force are no longer zero.  After the change, both $R$ and $a$ vary.  It will probably be easiest to work with the horizontal component in a rotating reference frame.  This eases the work of separating change of radius from centripetal acceleration.  However, doing so adds radius as a vector.  Use radius as the varying distance that you want to reach zero, rather than working with distance along the pipe.  This helps to keep the axes less entangled.